# Nature of Dependence in Bayesian Contingency Tables

Tags: bayesian, contingency-tables

Question from a novice in both R and Bayesian approaches.

I used the Bayes Factor package to calculate the BF for a contingency table of two nominal variables with 3 categories each and the results supported non-independence. Is there a way within the Bayesian framework to examine the magnitude of dependence? I was hoping for something analogous to Pearson residuals from the Chi-square test explained here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-test-of-independence-in-r

Thank you in advance for your input!

Answer (score 1):

It might help a bit to think about what the Bayesian and Frequentist models are testing.  The answer is "yes," and "no," depending on what you mean by the magnitude of dependence.

Dependence or independence are binary.  A relationship is either dependent or independent.  There is no magnitude of dependence.  You cannot be a little bit pregnant.

The Frequentist question is built around a null hypothesis.  The null is that the variables are independent.  The alternative is that they are not independent.

The Frequentist test is the probability of seeing data as extreme or more extreme due to chance alone, given that there is a 100% chance that the data is independent.  That is a very strong assumption.  However, the method is very conservative.

The Bayesian method is testing two hypotheses.  The first hypothesis is that $\Pr(A\text{ and }B)=\Pr(A)\times\Pr(B).$  The second is $\Pr(A\text{ and }B)=\Pr(B|A)\times\Pr(A).$  Given the data, what is the probability of either of these models being the true model?  There is no null to falsify, you are just testing the relative truth value.

Your software is likely going to marginalize out all of the parameter estimates except the Bayes factors.  If it did not, then the estimates of the parameters in $\Pr(B|A)\Pr(A)$ are your magnitudes.  Each parameter would have a distribution.

If it did marginalize it out, then you have two choices.  First, you could decide to look at functional forms. Is there a function out there that describes the relationship?  The simpler choice is to estimate $\Pr(\theta_{i,j}|data)$, where $\theta_{i,j}$ is the probability of being in the intersection of $A_i$ and $B_j$.  The joint distribution, if you used a conjugate prior, would be a Dirichlet distribution.  The distribution of each parameter would marginalize out to a beta distribution.  You could then calculate credible intervals as well with reasonable simplicity.

Comment: Thank you Dave! I’m using the Bayes factor package in R. Do you know if that package or any other R package can give me the parameter estimates, marginalized out or otherwise?